# Hessian of the Rayleigh quotient $\frac{\langle x,Ax\rangle}{\langle x,x\rangle}$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, hessian-matrix

I am struggling on the following question. Let $A$ be a semidefinite positive matrix ($A\in\mathscr{S}_n^+(\mathbb{R})$) and let consider the Rayleigh quotient defined as:

$$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n\backslash 0,~f(x):=\frac{\langle x,Ax\rangle}{\langle x,x\rangle}. $$

How can we compute the Hessian of $f$ ? I have tried to do the Taylor expansion but couldn't get anything from there...

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why not use the quotient rule??

Comment: Hi @copper.hat, I don't know how to differentiate a gradient.

Comment: How would you normally compute a Hessian?

Comment: Try expanding the numerator and denominator in terms of the components of the vector $x =(x_1, \dots, x_n)$. The Hessian will be the matrix whose element in the $i^{\text{th}}$ row and $j^{\text{th}}$ column is given by $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\a{\alpha}  \def\b{\beta}  \def\l{\lambda}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\mt{\mapsto}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\hess#1#2#3{\grad{^2 #1}{#2\,\p #3}}
\def\Hess#1#2{\grad{^2 #1}{#2^2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
$Consider the scalar functions  (aka quadratic forms)
$$\eqalign{
\a &= x^TAx &\qiq d\a = \LR{2Ax}^Tdx \\
\b &= x^TBx &\qiq d\b = \LR{2Bx}^Tdx \\
}$$
whose ratio is a generalized Rayleigh quotient and
whose gradient can be calculated as
$$\eqalign{
\l &= \frac{\a}{\b} \\
d\l
 &= \frac{\b\,d\a-\a\,d\b}{\b^2}
 \;=\; 2\b^{-1}\LR{Ax-\l Bx}^Tdx \\
\grad{\l}{x} &= 2\b^{-1}\BR{A-\l B}x \;\doteq\; \c{g} \\
}$$
The Hessian is the gradient of $g$
$$\eqalign{
dg
 &= 2\b^{-1}\LR{A-\l B}\c{dx}
  - 2\b^{-1}\c{d\l}Bx
  - 2\b^{-2}\c{d\b}\LR{A-\l B}x \\
 &= 2\b^{-1}\LR{A-\l B}\c{dx}
  - 2\b^{-1}Bx\CLR{g^Tdx}
  - 2\b^{-2}\LR{A-\l B}x\CLR{2x^TB\,dx} \\
 &= 2\b^{-1}\BR{A-\l B - Bxg^T - gx^TB}\,dx \\
\grad gx &= 2\b^{-1}\BR{A-\l B - Bxg^T - gx^TB} \;\doteq\; \c{H} \\
}$$
Setting $B=I$ yields the gradient and Hessian for a simple Rayleigh quotient.